# Should I synchronize concurrent accesses to a Thread object aimed at interrupting it?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have this kind of code:

```
class Foo {
    private final Thread mainThread = ...;
    public void start() { this.mainThread.start(); }
    public void stop() { this.mainThread.interrupt(); }
}
```

Note that `Foo.mainThread` is kind enough to check every now and then if it was interrupted by someone, and in the case it cleanly exits.

Now in my application there are many threads that share a `Foo` and are possibly interested in stopping it. Is everything OK or should I be paranoid and declare `Foo.stop()` to be a synchronized method?

Comment: You have a1, a2 , a3 threads that all share 1 Foo thread. Then you have b1, which have 1 foo thread of its own. And then a c1, that have a Foo thread. Am I understaning you correctly?

Answer (score 4):

[`Thread.interrupt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--) basically just sets a flag. Certain operations, such as `Thread.sleep` will cause this flag to be checked, and an exception is thrown if the flag is set to true.

Provided you're handling [`InterruptedException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html)s
 properly*, there's no reason why two threads both setting the flag would be a problem.

So no. Don't bother synchronizing `stop`.

You probably do want to synchronize `start`, though. Starting a thread twice will result in a `IllegalThreadStateException`. I'd re-write that function like so**:

```
private boolean started = false;

public void start()
{
    if (started) return;

    synchronized(this)
    {
        if (!started)
        {
            this.mainThread.start();
            started = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a good article which [explains how `Thread.interrupt` works](http://www.yegor256.com/2015/10/20/interrupted-exception.html).

<sub>*By 'properly' I mean don't do anything strange, like perform an operation which can throw an `InterruptedException` while you're handling an `InterruptedException`. That would be silly.</sub>

<sub>**A simpler solution would synchronize the whole method, but may result in synchronizing too often. This way, we only synchronize if two threads both compete to start an un-started thread at exactly the same time, and never synchronize after that.</sub>